# Microsoft Certificate Authority Machine Template - add single label host name to SAN

Tags: certificate, ad-certificate-services

I would like to create a machine certificate template on a Microsoft Certificate Authority that includes the single label Active Directory (AD) Computer Names in the SAN.

I have tens of thousands of servers so I don't want this requested client side as I'll be pushing the template out via GPO.  I don't see the options to add but don't know why as both the FQDN and hostname are fields in AD.

I see a duplicate question to mine over 11 years ago and am hoping Microsoft has incorporated this ability at least a decade later!  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in Computer/Machine template adds host's FQDN into SAN extension, so there should not be any issues.

Speaking about NetBIOS name, they are not recommended for use in authentication protocols, because they lead to ambiguity. There are two major server certificate use cases: simple TLS authentication and AD client authentication. With AD-sourced subject population, ADCS targets 2nd use case which requires strong mapping between client certificate and account in AD.

NetBIOS names are unique only within single domain. In multi-domain forests, or forests with trusts, they can lead to ambiguity and potential identity spoofing. This is why AD CS natively supports only host's FQDN in SAN extension, because it uniquely identify client.

If you can accept identity spoofing and privilege escalation risks, you can write your own policy module for AD CS by implementing [ICertPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certpol/nn-certpol-icertpolicy) (and optionally, [ICertPolicy2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certpol/nn-certpol-icertpolicy2)) COM interface and registering it on a CA server.

Comment: Good answer. If this is for a dnsname type, and I assume it is, it appears that RFC 5280 requires a domain name component. And it specifies that although whitespace is a valid domain name, it is not valid for a SAN dnsname.  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#page-35

Comment: @GregAskew NetBIOS names qualify RFC requirements. Don't forget that single-label domains are supported. So name `example` may represent a host or domain component. Domain Controllers receive certificates with their domain names (without host part) in SAN as dnsName name type. In single-label domain it will be single label without dots.